# Borrow checker issue trying to pass a function pointer as paramerter

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am seeking help to understand why the borrow checker fails for the following minimal non-working example, and I would be very happy to learn how to correctly implement what I was trying to do:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

struct Foo {
    data: HashSet<usize>
}

impl Foo {
    fn test<'a, F, T>(&mut self, _operation: F) -> ()
    where F: Fn(&'a HashSet<usize>, &'a HashSet<usize>) -> T,
          T: Iterator<Item=&'a usize>
    {
        let update: HashSet<usize> = vec![4, 2, 9].into_iter().collect();
        self.data = _operation(&self.data, &update).copied().collect();
    }

    fn new() -> Self {
        Foo { data: HashSet::new() }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut foo: Foo = Foo::new();
    foo.test(HashSet::intersection);
}
```

My main source of confusion is that, if I replace the call to `_operation` with `HashSet::intersection`, the code compiles. I thought that the type of the parameter `_operation` would allow me to pass both `HashSet::intersection` and `HashSet::union` as operations here.

For the record, this is the error I receive:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src\main.rs:13:32
   |
13 |         self.data = _operation(&self.data, &update).copied().collect();
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined on the method body at 8:23...
  --> src\main.rs:8:23
   |
8  |     fn test<'a, F, T>(&mut self, _operation: F) -> ()
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src\main.rs:13:32
   |
13 |         self.data = _operation(&self.data, &update).copied().collect();
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the method body at 8:13...
  --> src\main.rs:8:13
   |
8  |     fn test<'a, F, T>(&mut self, _operation: F) -> ()
   |             ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src\main.rs:13:32
   |
13 |         self.data = _operation(&self.data, &update).copied().collect();
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0495`.
error: could not compile `aoc06` due to previous error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, as the (albeit cryptic) compiler message suggests, is that there is a lifetime mismatch: `_operation` expects `HashSet` references that live as long as `'a`, but `&self.data` has a lifetime `'b`, the elided lifetime of `&mut self`, and `&update` has a different lifetime that lasts the duration of the `test` function body.

To resolve this issue, we must specify that the function type `F` takes in `HashMap` references of *arbitrary* lifetimes, not just the specific lifetime `'a` -- this lets the compiler infer the appropriate lifetime when `_operation` is invoked. This is why we need [Higher-Rank Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) (HRTBs):

```
fn test<F, T>(&mut self, _operation: F) -> ()
    where F: for<'a> Fn(&'a HashSet<usize>, &'a HashSet<usize>) -> T,
```

However, this raises another issue. How do we apply the higher-ranked lifetime `'a` to the type parameter `T`? Unfortunately Rust [does not support higher-kinded types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/324), but we can get away with "abstracting" out the the function type `F` and the higher-kinded type `T` to a trait and an associated type on said trait.

```
trait Operation<'a, T: 'a> {
    type Output: Iterator<Item = &'a T>;
    fn operate(self, a: &'a HashSet<T>, b: &'a HashSet<T>) -> Self::Output;
}
```

The `Operation` trait represents an operation on two `HashSet`s that returns an iterator over references, equivalent to the functions `HashSet::union`, `HashSet::intersection`, and the like. We can achieve this using the following `impl`, which ensures that `HashSet::intersection` and the like implement `Operation`:

```
impl<'a, T: 'a, I, F> Operation<'a, T> for F
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a T>,
    F: FnOnce(&'a HashSet<T>, &'a HashSet<T>) -> I,
{
    type Output = I;

    fn operate(self, a: &'a HashSet<T>, b: &'a HashSet<T>) -> Self::Output {
        self(a, b)
    }
}
```

We can then use a HRTB on the *`Operation`* trait instead, which does not require any nested higher-kinded types:

```
fn test(&mut self, _operation: impl for<'a> Operation<'a, usize>) -> () {
    let update: HashSet<usize> = vec![4, 2, 9].into_iter().collect();
    self.data = _operation.operate(&self.data, &update).copied().collect();
    println!("{:?}", self.data);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a7cc213b3cd8ca18bcf757adc81af84d)

Comment: Thank you so much! The two answers here were extremely helpful in understanding lifetime bounds better. You won the coinflip for accepted answer =). See the comment below for a link to the actual code that inspired this question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The arguments you are passing do not match the lifetime which you declared the `Fn` bound with.

```rust
fn test<'a, F, T>(&mut self, _operation: F) -> ()
```

`'a` is **some arbitrary lifetime that may be specified by the caller,**

```rust
    F: Fn(&'a HashSet<usize>, &'a HashSet<usize>) -> T,
```

which must be adequate for the references given to `_operation`,

```
        let update: HashSet<usize> = vec![4, 2, 9].into_iter().collect();
        self.data = _operation(&self.data, &update).copied().collect();
```

but here you pass in a borrow from `self` (whose lifetime is not specified to outlive `'a`) and a borrow from `update` (which is a local variable, which *cannot* outlive `'a`).

---

In order to correctly write this, you need to specify that `_operation` may be called with *any* lifetime (which thus includes the lifetimes of borrows of local variables). That's simple, by itself:

```rust
    fn test<F, T>(&mut self, _operation: F) -> ()
    where
        F: for<'a> Fn(&'a HashSet<usize>, &'a HashSet<usize>) -> T,
```

Note that `'a` is no longer a lifetime parameter of `test`. Instead it's part of the bound on `F`: you can read this `for<'a>` notation as “**for *any* lifetime,** which we will call `'a`, `F` may be called as a function with references `&'a ...`”.

However, this isn't actually a solution, because you also have `T: Iterator<Item = &'a usize>`, which uses `'a` again. It isn't currently possible to write a `where` clause that expresses this relationship, particularly as even without the item being a reference, the iterator will be borrowing the `&'a HashSet`s.

This is an unfortunate limitation of current Rust — it also comes up in trying to write a function that takes an async function which borrows an input (which is structurally the same as your situation, with `Future` in place of `Iterator`). However, there is a workaround: you can **define a trait for the function,** which has a single lifetime parameter that links everything together. (This doesn't impose any extra work on the caller of your function, because the trait is blanket implemented for all suitable functions.)

Here's your code with such a trait added and the needed modifications to `fn test()`:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

trait IteratorCallback<'a> {
    type Output: Iterator<Item = &'a usize> + 'a;
    fn call(self, a: &'a HashSet<usize>, b: &'a HashSet<usize>) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<'a, F, T> IteratorCallback<'a> for F
where
    F: FnOnce(&'a HashSet<usize>, &'a HashSet<usize>) -> T,
    T: Iterator<Item = &'a usize> + 'a,
{
    type Output = T;
    fn call(self, a: &'a HashSet<usize>, b: &'a HashSet<usize>) -> T {
        // Delegate to FnOnce
        self(a, b)
    }
}

struct Foo {
    data: HashSet<usize>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn test<F>(&mut self, _operation: F) -> ()
    where
        F: for<'a> IteratorCallback<'a>,
    {
        let update: HashSet<usize> = vec![4, 2, 9].into_iter().collect();
        self.data = _operation.call(&self.data, &update).copied().collect();
    }

    fn new() -> Self {
        Foo {
            data: HashSet::new(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo: Foo = Foo::new();
    foo.test(HashSet::intersection);
}
```

Note: I changed the function bound to `FnOnce` because that's more permissive than `Fn` and all you need in this case, but the same technique will work with `Fn` as long as you change `fn call(self,` to `fn call(&self,`.

Credit: I used [this Reddit comment by user Lej77](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/hey4oa/help_lifetimes_on_async_functions_with_callbacks/fvv1zql/?context=3) as an example to work from for the trait technique.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It was practically impossible to choose which answer to accept, because it was really the combination of yours and the above one that finally helped us grok it. Turns out we had to modify the trait bound a little more to require that `F` also implements `Copy` because we actually want to call this in a loop; This was for Advent of Code 2020, task #6. Here's the actual code, we are super happy with the result: https://github.com/baerenbrot/advent-of-code/blob/main/2020/aoc06/src/main.rs