# Typing a closure that returns an anonymous type borrowing from one of its inputs without heap allocation or trait objects

Tags: rust, lifetime

Let's say that I have the following working code:

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn modify<S, F>(state: &mut S, func: F)
where
    F: for<'a> Fn(&'a mut S) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &mut u64> + 'a>
{
    let mut prev = 1;
    for _ in 0..3 {
        for item in func(state) {
            let val = *item;
            *item = val * prev;
            prev = val;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut state: VecDeque<u64> = vec![1,2,3,4].into();

    modify(&mut state, |s| Box::new(s.iter_mut()));
    assert_eq!(state, [48, 8, 24, 864]);

    modify(&mut state, |s| Box::new(s.iter_mut().take(2)));
    assert_eq!(state, [147456, 7077888, 24, 864]);

    modify(&mut state, |s| Box::new(s.iter_mut().skip(2)));
    assert_eq!(state, [147456, 7077888, 429981696, 10319560704]);
}
```

`modify` takes a function that generates an iterator multiple times from a given `state` variable (in this case, a `VecDeque`). This function works, but contains an unnecessary heap allocation as well as unneeded polymorphism in the form of a trait object. I'd very much like to do something like this:

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn modify<'a, S, F, I>(state: &'a mut S, func: F)
where
    F: Fn(&'a mut S) -> I,
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a mut u64>
{
    let mut prev = 1;
    for _ in 0..3 {
        for item in func(state) {
            let val = *item;
            *item = val * prev;
            prev = val;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut state: VecDeque<u64> = vec![1,2,3,4].into();

    modify(&mut state, |s| s.iter_mut());
    assert_eq!(state, [48, 8, 24, 864]);

    modify(&mut state, |s| s.iter_mut().take(2));
    assert_eq!(state, [147456, 7077888, 24, 864]);

    modify(&mut state, |s| s.iter_mut().skip(2));
    assert_eq!(state, [147456, 7077888, 429981696, 10319560704]);
}
```

But I now get this error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*state` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:10:26
   |
3  | fn modify<'a, S, F, I>(state: &'a mut S, func: F)
   |           -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
10 |         for item in func(state) {
   |                     -----^^^^^-
   |                     |    |
   |                     |    `*state` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
   |                     argument requires that `*state` is borrowed for `'a`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
```

And I can't figure out how to wrangle the borrow checker to do what I want. Any clues would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

No, not until [closure HRTB inference](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/70263) is fixed. Current workarounds include using function pointers instead or implementing a helper trait on custom structs -- the helper trait is needed regardless of approach until higher-kinded types are introduced in Rust.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=007ceec9284d410f39c5156d838a0d5e)

## Details

To avoid returning a `Box`, you would need the type parameter `I` to be *generic* over the lifetime `'a`, so that you can use it with any lifetime (in a `for<'a>` bound, for example). Unfortunately, as discussed in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70149077/4038191), Rust does not yet support higher-kinded types (type parameters that are themselves generic over other type parameters), so we must use a helper trait:

```
trait GenerateIterator<'a, S: 'a> {
    type Output: Iterator<Item = &'a mut u64>;
    fn generate(self, s: &'a mut S) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<'a, S: 'a, I, F> GenerateIterator<'a, S> for F
where
    F: Fn(&'a mut S) -> I,
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a mut u64>,
{
    type Output = I;
    fn generate(self, s: &'a mut S) -> Self::Output {
        self(s)
    }
}

fn modify<S>(state: &mut S, func: impl for<'a> GenerateIterator<'a, S>) {
    let mut prev = 1;
    for _ in 0..3 {
        for item in func.generate(state) {
            let val = *item;
            *item = val * prev;
            prev = val;
        }
    }
}
```

This is great in helping us work around the use of higher-kinded types in this situation, but due to [another compiler limitation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/70263) in closure HRTB (higher-ranked trait bound) inference, the compiler is unable to infer that the closures we pass to `modify` are general over any lifetime. The alternative is to use function pointers like `VecDeque::iter_mut`, or create your own `struct`s that implement `GenerateIterator` to generate the `Iterator` as you want:

```
fn main() {
    fn take2(s: &mut VecDeque<u64>) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut u64> {
        s.iter_mut().take(2)
    }

    fn skip2(s: &mut VecDeque<u64>) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut u64> {
        s.iter_mut().skip(2)
    }

    let mut state: VecDeque<u64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4].into();

    modify(&mut state, VecDeque::iter_mut);
    assert_eq!(state, [48, 8, 24, 864]);

    modify(&mut state, take2);
    assert_eq!(state, [147456, 7077888, 24, 864]);

    modify(&mut state, skip2);
    assert_eq!(state, [147456, 7077888, 429981696, 10319560704]);
}
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the comprehensive answer. I always thought that having higher kinded types would have helped, but I thought there had to be a way to do it because it works with trait objects, so I reasoned that there should be no reason it shouldn't work the same with concrete types. Bummer for now, hope this gets fixed/added soon!